Improving the efficiency of storing millions of instances of 2-UUID structs to disk in short time
In my application, I need to store millions of custom structs that contain 2 UUID attributes to disk. My project requires these to be written & read to disk very quickly. I tried using JSONDecoder but found the performance to be very slow for saving around 100k to around 10 million of these structs which took from anywhere around 3 to 30 seconds as tested thoroughly.
Is there a much more efficient way to store a struct with just 2 UUIDs such as using a binary representation? I was unable to find any resources on saving UUIDs to disk. I do not need the format to be JSON for both saving to and reading from disk.
struct MetadataItem: Identifiable, Codable {
    var id = UUID()
    let itemId: UUID
}

//Just to simulate adding the custom structs
for i in 1...1000000 {
     let newItem = MetadataItem(itemId: UUID())
     metadataItems.append(newItem)
}
                            
do {
    let data = try JSONEncoder().encode(metadataItems)
    if let url = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first {
        try data.write(to: url.appending(path: "Metadata"))
    }
    
    print("Done")
} catch {

}


CoreData? The issue with a JSON array is that you need to read and write all of the values at once, so changing or appending a single value requires you to read the whole array and then rewrite it. Any time you deal with IO and 10 million it may take some time. You need to provide more details.  Is this a one time operation?  Do you need to be able to search this data? Is the data updated, deleted or added to? How often does this occur?

I did try core data but it was too slow to save lots of these data averaging around 5 seconds or much more even for 100k of these records. My app requires the data to be saved and read back as quickly as possible for at least a million of these UUID structs. I do  need to traverse the uuid array to get the correct one but other than that no need for quick searching. These UUIDs are just meant to fetch the related Core data entities actually. The data is not updated too frequently.

I furthermore need ordering of these structs but in core data, that would require unnecessary index attributes to reindex when updated or another entity to have a relationship with so that the many relationship would be ordered which means NSBatchInsertRequest is out of the question which cannot be used to set relationships. So I have no other choice

Then one technique you could use is to simply write each itemId to a file that is named by its id. With so many files you would probably need to implement a directory structure. You could take the first four characters of the id and use that for a series of directories, so for id 1234-abc123-def789-0987 you would have the file path 1/2/3/4/1234-abc123-def789-0987. This would give you about 150 files per final directory for 10 million IDs.

It is also important to understand if these 10 million records are written once or repeatedly. A single 30 second set up on the initial launch might be ok as you can show an activity view and explain what is happening. Individual reads and writes would be fast.

You can also use SQLite directly, but I don't think you are going to find any way to create 10 million records in zero time.

I see. I was wondering what about PropertyListEncoders with output format as binary, is that faster and efficient than json encoder?

Looking through some of your other questions I think you need to rethink your fundamental approach. Is it really necessary to maintain a strict order of 10 million (or even 10k) items in a playlist?  A user can't manage that.  All they need to see is the next 10 or 20 items and have the ability to add a new item to the head of the queue (or possibly at some other point in the queue). You can even fetch more items to play as they scroll the list. Then you are just managing the items that are going to be played and the items that have recently been played.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

One of the biggest reasons is Apple Music and Spotify instantly load up their up next queue in the correct playlist order even for 100k song playlists after testing when they’re downloaded for offline listening. So I was trying to implement similar to that

You could try saving the two UUID to file or
zip file, as comma separated strings (or better still, its binary representation).
For example, id.uuidString, itemId.uuidString, then recreate
the structs/UUID from the strings if need be.

How do I save the binary representation of the struct?

For the uuid, use: id.uuidString.data(using: .utf8) for the whole struct
you could use NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData...

If anyone is wondering, after testing myself more versions of the method as suggested by "workingdog", it is magnitudes more faster to convert the UUIDs to Data using the .uuid property and then writing to disk compared to using the string version instead.
After testing, this is what I got for storing 1 million of these structs to disk from slowest to fastest...
PropertyListEncoder: 4.46s
JSONEncoder: 3.37s
Converting UUID to string: 1.13s
Converting UUID to uuid data bytes: 345ms
func metadataItemsToBinary(items: [MetadataItem]) -> Data {
    var data = Data()
    for item in items {
        data.append(withUnsafeBytes(of: item.id.uuid) { Data($0) })
        data.append(withUnsafeBytes(of: item.itemId.uuid) { Data($0) })
    }

    return data
}


Likely you'll get the fastest performance if you write custom file manager code that does random access file writing with fixed-length records, writing binary data.

To convert a MetadataItem to binary, then to read it back,
you could try this approach, as shown in the example code.
Note, I have not tested this for efficiency.
struct MetadataItem: Identifiable, Codable {
    var id: UUID  // <--- here
    let itemId: UUID
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("testing")
            .onAppear {
                // test struct
                let metadataItem = MetadataItem(id: UUID(), itemId: UUID())
                print("---> metadataItem: \(metadataItem)\n")

                // convert to binary
                let binaryData = metadataItemToBinary(item: metadataItem)
                print("------> binaryData: \(binaryData)")
                
                // write to file
                
                // read from file
                
                // then recreate the struct
                if let restoredItem = binaryToMetadataItem(data: binaryData) {
                    print("\n---> restored item: \(restoredItem)")
                }
            }
    }
    
    func metadataItemToBinary(item: MetadataItem) -> Data {
        var data = Data()
        data.append(item.id.uuidString.data(using: .utf8)!)
        data.append(item.itemId.uuidString.data(using: .utf8)!)
        print("------> data: \(data)")
        return data
    }
    
    func binaryToMetadataItem(data: Data) -> MetadataItem? {
        guard data.count == 72 else {
            return nil
        }
        let idData = data.subdata(in: 0..<36)
        let itemIdData = data.subdata(in: 36..<72)
        
        if let id = UUID(uuidString: String(data: idData, encoding: .utf8)!),
           let itemId = UUID(uuidString: String(data: itemIdData, encoding: .utf8)!) {
            print("------> id: \(id)  itemId: \(itemId)")
            return MetadataItem(id: id, itemId: itemId)
        } else {
            // deal with errors
            return nil
        }
    }
}

EDIT-1:
for an array test:
    .onAppear {
        // test array of MetadataItem
        let arr: [MetadataItem] = [MetadataItem(id: UUID(), itemId: UUID()), MetadataItem(id: UUID(), itemId: UUID())]
        print("---> arr: \(arr)\n")

        // convert to binary
        var binarr: [Data] = arr.map{metadataItemToBinary(item: $0)}

        // recover the structs
        print("---> restored")
        binarr.forEach{ data in
            if let restoredItem = binaryToMetadataItem(data: data) {
                print("---> item: \(restoredItem)")
            }
        }
    }


How do I instead append an array of MetadataItem to the Data instance in your function and get back an array of MetadataItem as well? Can I just append straight on using a map function?

I have described the tools here, for how to convert a MetadataItem to binary,
then to convert it back to a struct.
For an array of such, well just simply add to an array and do the same.

wow, your method was so so much faster for a million metadata items compared to JSON Encoder or PropertyLisEncoder.. Wondered whether the binary representation will be much faster. Indeed it is magnitudes faster than either of those.

updated my answer with using arrays. Thanks, glad it works for you.
